# Passing different modifiers to each composable inside a NavHost

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack

I have a `NavHost` which hosts all the `composable`s of my app. I would like to be able to pass different `Modifier`s to each `composable` because the size of the screen should change depending on which screen is currently visible.

I have tried changing the modifier of the `NavHost` itself depending on the screen, however this causes buggy animations when switching between `composable`s and the result is not pleasing at all.

I was thinking about making the `NavHost` size static and change the size of each individual composable, but I don't know how to pass `Modifier`s to `composable`s inside the NavHost.

What can I do?

Note: Please don't suggest hardcoding `Modifier` inside `composable` because I want the `Modifier` to be able to change even for the same `composable`

Comment: I do not understand what you try to achieve. The `NavHost` usually is located in a surface that fills the entire window. Since the NavHost itself doesn't consume any space, the composables you host in it will have that entire window to themselves, except maybe for a navigation rail/bar. Now, what do you intend to do with those composables? What do you mean by resizing? Resize to what? Why not let the composables just take all the space that is available - independent of how much exactly that is?

Comment: My app's layout is basically a footer (containig a bottom nav bar and some other stuff), and above it is my `NavHost`. This footer changes its offset vertically depending on a few things and I would like to expand or shrink the space given to the composables inside the `NavHost` to take up the available space by giving them a custom Modifier. Giving the modifier directly to the NavHost results in buggy animations because the size can change during transitions, so I want to find a way to pass the modifiers directly to the composables themselves while leaving the NavHost size static @Leviathan

Comment: When your footer moves to the top, the navhost will have less space. Just let the composables take up the entire space left to the navhost. When your footer moves to the bottom, the navhost will have less space. But the same applies: Just let the composables take up the entire space left to the navhost. I still don't see how you need to resize anything regarding the navhost or its composables. Please provide an illustration that explains what you really want to achieve.